# Vamos "desconfigurar" a tag [configuração]?

Tags: debate, tags, tag-específica

Eu pessoalmente não vejo utilidade para tag [configuração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/configura%c3%a7%c3%a3o), muita coisa é configuração, desde a parte da instalação de um software, até configurar um script para funcionar conforme requisitos prévios, todavia acho a tag totalmente redundante.

Pensei em remover todas perguntas (assim a tag em algumas horas/dias irá sumir), todavia vim perguntar o que acham disto?

Comment: Não sei se é o caso para matá-la. O que vejo muito em *tags* sendo usadas de forma errada. Esse é um problema. Para matar uma *tag* eu acho que ela tem que ser completamente sem sentido ou bem problemática. SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/configuration e tem variações

Comment: Concordo com o @bigown. Nem toda tag precisa ser completamente auto-contida e auto-suficiente. `[configuração]` tem sua utilidade na organização so site. Se você vem vendo mal uso dela, o melhor a fazer é corrigir e instruir.

Comment: Eu não consigo imaginar a utilidade da tag configuração, mesmo olhando no SOen. Por mim matava.

Comment: @Math concordo.

Comment: @Math tag "configuração" no SOPT parece "Gordura" aparecendo num cardápio. não tem por quê :D

Comment: -1 por não ter escrito "vamos **desconfigurar** a tag [configuração]". :p

Comment: @DanielGomes "vamos desconfigurar a tag [configuração]"!

Comment: Eu fiquei curioso sobre a utilidade prolongada da tag ao longo do tempo, na suspeita de que ela talvez fosse um "resquício" de outras épocas, e realmente não se encaixasse no SO moderno. Olhei a média de pontuação das perguntas ao longo dos anos e ela se comporta exatamente como o resto do site. A pontuação média vai pra próximo de 0 e o número total de votos também diminui. No final das contas, totalmente inconclusivo. A decisão de manter ou remover a tag vai ter que se basear no potencial de bom uso dela, se existir.

Comment: A tag sozinha talvez seja mesmo sem sentido, mas se estiver junto com outra tag tem algum valor. Exemplo: `apache + configuração`, `php + configuração`, `git + configuração`

Comment: @DanielOmine Mas isso não caracterizaria uma [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)?

Comment: Não sei dizer..

Comment: @DanielOmine desculpe mas discordo, se for assim todas perguntas que for sobre gravar .txt com fopen no php em uma pasta, teriam que ter as tags `php`+`arquivo`+`pasta`, todas perguntas que forem sobre acessar urls com php, teriam que as tag `php`+`url`, e se o conteúdo desta url for gravado ou copiado em um arquivo, teria que ter `php`+`url`+`arquivo`.

Comment: Acho que aí está exagerando com esses exemplos pois uma coisa não justifica outra, @GuilhermeNascimento. Mas de minha parte eu não me importo se a tag existir ou não.. é indiferente. E para deixar claro, talvez estejam confundindo o sinal de mais +. Ali é como se fossem duas tags separadas e não 2 tags unidas pelo sinal de +. Seria `apache` e `configuração` e não `apache + configuração`.  Isso é só um exemplo, sacou... blz?  rsrs

Comment: rsr.. ah.. o negativo ali não é meu não.. então nem vem achar que fui eu... kkk

Comment: @DanielOmine não entendi mal o seu exemplo das tags e só estou tentando explicar que colocar uma tag como [configuração] para um problema de funcionamento é comparável as outras tags que citei. PS: Negativos no META não fazem diferença, são opinativos, e só para constar, sou diferente da maioria das pessoas que negativam procurando qualquer "desculpa" apenas por **picunhas** do passado, então não se preocupe, a unica coisa que procuro são que justifiquem seus downvotes para que eu tente melhorar, assim como se eu lhe der um downvote pode ter certeza que irei dizer o motivo.

Comment: Entendido, só acho que os exemplos que postou no comentário são meio forçados. Teem menos relevância do que o termo em questão que é "configuração". Na verdade eu estava concordando com a sua questão até ler o comentário do @Gabe, especialmente a última frase. Então logo me veio essa ideia que tentei expressar no comentário. Mas é uma divagação qualquer e talvez seja bobagem. Quem é mais habituado com o sistema e principalmente quem desenvolve o sistema talvez consiga enxergar se é relevante ou não.

Comment: @DanielOmine Independente da tag, o contexto para pessoas experientes vai parecer um e para pessoas inexperiente outro, talvez arquivo e pasta soe uma coisa para ti, no entanto para usuários novatos `configuração`, `arquivo`, `pasta`, `if`, `variavel`, etc vão parecer todas "importante".

Comment: Quando tiver esses termos exagerados bastaria removê-los. É óbvio que `pasta`, `variavel`, `if` e coisas assim não faz sentido estar nas tags. E óbvio também que inexperientes vão usar até o nome do cachorro nas tags. Sempre vejo uso irregular nas tags por parte dos novatos. Agora a questão que vc levantou é se o termo "configuração" também não deveria ser removido. Pois então, conforme comentei mais de uma vez, concordo, faz sentido, mas o comment do Gabe me fez divagar sobre alguma utilidade. Enfim, está descrito no comentarios acima.. rsrsr..

Comment: @DanielOmine não entendeu, novamente, como disse, para umas pessoas A soa como exagero e B não, para outras pessoas ambos soam como exagero.

Comment: A mim também me parece inútil.

Comment: Estou trabalhando na *tags* e tem casos bem piores (nem sei se dá para dizer que este é ruim. Todos podem caçar problemas maiores que este. De qualquer forma debates como este serão mais produtivos se tiver alguns exemplos claros que mostram que a *tag* é inútil e alguns que fica em uma linha tênue fica mais fácil saber do está se falando concretamente.

Comment: @bigown para estes casos piores tem uma razoável solução: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5094/3635